# regular expression  to remove substrings delimited by matching double braces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a string like this:

```
adfsdf dsf  {{sadfsdfadf {{Infobox}} musical}} jljlk }}
```

I want eliminate all `{{..}}` substrings. I tried

```
\{\{.*\}\}
```

which eliminates `{{sadfsdfadf{{Infobox}} musical}} jljlk }}` but I want eliminate `{{sadfsdfadf {{Infobox}} musical}}`, checking the `}}` closer to the start of the substring.

How can I do this?

Comment: Note that this will fail in strange ways if there is any kind of recursion in the string, e.g.: running that regex on  `{{ text {{ text }} text }}` will leave the last `}}`, even though there are two pairs of `{{` and `}}`'s.

Answer (score 3):

Use a lazy quantifier:

```
\{\{.*?\}\}
```

Comment: This is no good: in the original example, it will only go up to the brackets just after "Infobox", leaving "musical}}" when it shouldn't.

Comment: You can keep running this all you want, and it'll never do what the poster wants. As you would instantly see if you tried it even once.

Comment: @glenn, the example posted by Luca has changed since I posted my answer. What he not wants will only work with Regex engines supporting some kind of recursion, such as the .NET Regex or the PHP preges AFAIR.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly non-robust expression `\{\{[a-zA-Z\s]*\}\}` that will work.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, this won't be possible with regular expressions. You cannot match balanced parentheses, or anything like that, with a regular expression-- you need a context-free grammar instead.

That said, Perl has some facilities for recursive regular expressions; these would allow you to do what you want. I do not know if Ruby is capable of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example using a recent 1.9.x Ruby version. If you run an 1.8.x release you'll need the oniguruma gem. This doesn't take into account escaped `\{\{` but does handle single `{` and `}` which I assume you will want to ignore.

```
#!/usr/bin/evn ruby
# Old 1.8.x versions of Ruby you'll need the gem.
# require 'oniguruma'
require 'pp'

squiggly = %r/
  (
    (?<squiggly>         # squiggly named group
      \{\{               # start {{
        (?:              # non matching group
          [^{}]          # anything not { or }
          | \{[^{]       # any { not followed by {
          | \}[^}]       # any } not followed by }
          | \g<squiggly> # nested squiggly
        )*               # zero or more times
      \}\}               # end }}
    )                    # end of squiggly
  )/x

string = 'adfsdf dsf  {{sadfsdfadf {{Infobox}} musical}} jljlk }}'
pp squiggly.match(string)[:squiggly] #=> {{sadfsdfadf {{Infobox}} musical}}
```

Comment: Nice one!  I *thought* I'd heard Oniguruma had recursive matching.  Are there any good English-language docs for it out there?  The standard feature list dissolves into gibberish just when it's starting to get interesting: http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt :-/

Comment: Sorry, everything I know about oniguruma I picked up from that page or in practice.